# Difference between vsphere 5.5 and vsphere 6

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-player, vmware-tools

What are the main difference between vsphere 5.5 and vsphere 6? Are there any feature additions? Are they backwards compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this table for a comparison

[image: Comparison Char]

Answer (score 0):

Vsphere 6/6.5 are a major departure from 5.5. There are a number of small changes but the 2 biggest you will likely notice is that in 6+ they deprecated the c# vCenter client and are moving vCenter to an in house linux based appliance system instead of hosting it on windows.

Answer (score 0):

vSphere 6.5 used the HTML5 to access the vCenter data center management. access from any system in google chrome. completly deprecated the windows based Thin client.

Lot of feature added like HCI - Hyper converged infrastructure.

In this all your compute storage and Network will be integrated with single device.

You can reduce the manual task for management task. creating switch and deploying the configuration in multiple data center with same configuration. replication job will easy.

[You can find more info](http://www.vmwarearena.com/vsphere-6-0-difference-between-vsphere-5-0-5-1-5-5-and-vsphere-6-0/)